# Hide a column on smaller screens for Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

This is one area that always confuses me with Bootstrap 4

Say you have this layout:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">     
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3">col-sm-3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">col-sm-9</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

What classes do you to assign ( most likely to the `col-sm-3` ) such that the `col-sm-3` is hidden on: `xs`, `sm` and `md` ?

In other words and just to be clear I only want the `col-sm-3` to show up on `lg` and `xl` screens?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use [display utilities classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements), in this case:

`d-none d-lg-block`: hide on screens smaller than lg

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">     
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 d-none d-lg-block">col-sm-3</div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">col-sm-9</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/ and could not make heads or tails of it. Your solution seems to work fine. I will test some more too. Thanks Jim

Comment: same thing in v4.0 or v4.1

Comment: OK it works fine. I was also testing my page with a jQuery .resize function and the col-sm-3 gets hidden right around 992 going down to 991 pixels.  And in fact here it is in the docs. // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... } https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer". This is different in that it gets right to the point. And is easily understood. While the Missing visible-** and hidden-** in Bootstrap v4 most likely provides a thorough and exhaustive explanation of all cases, I am still having trouble with it. If the purpose of SO is to convey knowledge from one person to another I believe the question I asked and the way it was answered is crystal clear.

Comment: Actually there is more here. If the question was, " I only want the col-sm-3 to show up on md,  lg and xl screens"  Dippas actually answered that question too!  It would be <div class="col-sm-3 d-none d-md-block">col-sm-3</div>